# How to add Paypal-android-sdk in libs folder of cordova phonegap project?

Tags: android, cordova, paypal, sdk, phonegap-plugins

I installed paypal cordova plugin in my phone-gap app. 
For paypal integration in my app, I have download the zip file of paypal-android-sdk from the source given https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK.

Now I just want to know how do I add PayPal-Android-SDK in my phone-gap's project's libs folder so that paypal plugin works perfectly.

Please suggest me for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

- Create cordova app with same name as that of app created in paypal developer account.
- Include the paypal plugin in config.xml

`<plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" spec="3.1.23" />`

- Add the paypal-mobile-js-helper.js file to the app using script tag in index.html

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>`
- Follow the guidelines from documentation https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin